# Make datatables search the column.render value instead of value returned from server

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

Am using server side processing on datatables and one of the values returned is either `0` or `1` don't want datatables to search or filter on these so i do this in the datatables.

```
  {"data":"Cycle.type", "targets":3, "render": function (data,type,full,meta) {
           return data == '0' ?'<td> Planning</td>' : '<td>Realization</td>';
   }}
```

It seems datatables still searches on the value returned serverside but I want it to search on the values returned by the render function above. There is some html but am mainly interested in the values in the Html tags. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you disable sorting/searching on that particular column using `bSortable: false` and `bSearchable: false`?

Comment: @Beginner I have edited the the question a bit. Maybe it will make more sense.  Sorting works fine but searching still uses the values returned serverside.

Comment: So disable search for that column.

Comment: @Beginner This is not what I want achieve. I still want he column to be searchable but I want the rendered values not the values returned serverside

Comment: But the search will be server side too. So why don't you modify your server side function?

Comment: @Beginner Indeed you are right

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using server-side processing, searching and ordering must be done on the server side too.

If you're using PHP, you can use `ssp.class.php` that is available when you [download DataTables library](https://datatables.net/download/download).

With `ssp.class.php` you can use the following trick with sub-query to make numerical field searchable. Shown below is just a simple example.

```php
<?php

$table = <<<EOT
 (
    SELECT 
       field1, 
       field2, 
       (CASE WHEN type=0 THEN 'Planning' ELSE 'Realization' END) AS type
    FROM table
 ) temp
EOT;

$primaryKey = 'id';

$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'field1',  'dt' => 'field1' ),
    array( 'db' => 'field2',  'dt' => 'field2' ),
    array( 'db' => 'type',    'dt' => 'type' )
);

// SQL server connection information
$sql_details = array(
    'user' => '',
    'pass' => '',
    'db'   => '',
    'host' => ''
);

require( 'ssp.class.php' );

echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
?>
```

To use that trick, you also need to edit `ssp.class.php` and replace all instances of `` FROM `$table` `` with `FROM $table` to remove backticks.

Comment: This is a bright solution, but would a custom filter not be better after all? I think, if something changes on the client - you have to correct serverside too. But +1.

Comment: @davidkonrad, can you please explain what you mean by custom filters, [this example](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html), maybe? If yes, I don't think it is possible with server-side processing. Am I missing more elegant solution?

Comment: something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29602026/jquery-datatables-to-exclude-rows-with-a-certain-class/29606275#29606275) I **could** produce an answer, but I trust Gyrocode :)