# Exclude First TR from filtering and sorting - DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I would like to exclude the first row of my table which is in `tbody` from sorting and filtering.

I have tried [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29602026/jquery-datatables-to-exclude-rows-with-a-certain-class),

Thanks in advance, I'm new to using DataTables. (I'm porting an existing website to a new one using Laravel)

The "this method" doesn't work... also not sure what to do as documentation doesn't give any help (I looked through it, perhaps I just missed it)

Edit: I use this `var oTable = $('#new_table').DataTable();`

also i tried using this, but it doesnt work, it for an old version of datatables, i'm using the latest version.

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
    function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
        var row = oSettings.aoData[iDataIndex].nTr;
        return $(row).hasClass('template') ? false : true;
    }
);
```

Comment: please update your questions with details:  example code you tried, and explain "doesn't work".  The thread you linked obviously worked for the OP in that question.  We can't infer why it's not working for you.

Comment: @devlincarnate see edit.

Comment: So, that's referencing a plug-in.  Have you tried using the [DataTables documentation](https://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/) to set up the plug-ins?  They also have examples for how to use...

Comment: i have looked at the docs man, i just need to exclude the first row from the filtering @devlincarnate